# Shutter is complaining about that can't locate Carp/Always.pm in @INC

Tags: perl, shutter

I made a full upgrade from Ubuntu v18 to Ubuntu v20.

Shutter was not upgraded - it was removed.
I was trying to install from [CRAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_(programming_language)#Packages) or from source.
Both complain about old Perl libraries.

When I am trying to compile from source and run it, this is the message I get...
I read somewhere that I can have two Perl installations in my system. However, I do not know if the problem is of that kind - does it require for an older version of Perl or is it a problem of paths?

Using find / search I cannot locate the file "always.pm" (after some minutes, I break it).

```
shutter
```

Results:

```
Can't locate Carp/Always.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Carp::Always module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.30.0 /usr/local/share/perl/5.30.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.30 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.30 /usr/share/perl/5.30 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base) at /usr/local/bin/shutter line 39.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/bin/shutter line 39 (#1)
    (F) You said to do (or require, or use) a file that couldn't be found.
    Perl looks for the file in all the locations mentioned in @INC, unless
    the file name included the full path to the file.  Perhaps you need
    to set the PERL5LIB or PERL5OPT environment variable to say where the
    extra library is, or maybe the script needs to add the library name
    to @INC.  Or maybe you just misspelled the name of the file.  See
    "require" in perlfunc and lib.

Uncaught exception from user code:
    Can't locate Carp/Always.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Carp::Always module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.30.0 /usr/local/share/perl/5.30.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.30 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.30 /usr/share/perl/5.30 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base) at /usr/local/bin/shutter line 39.
    BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/bin/shutter line 39.
```

By issuing

```
 sudo apt-get install --reinstall libcarp-always-perl
```

results (even hugin is removed. I didn't change much and I don’t want it to be removed):

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 hugin : Depends: libglew2.0 (>= 1.12.0) but it is not installable
         Depends: libomp5 (>= 0.20140926) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

By issuing:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

Results:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libtiff4 libtiffxx0c2
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  hugin
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 15 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 275 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
```

By issuing (the repository is already there)

```
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

it results in:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 hugin : Depends: libglew2.0 (>= 1.12.0) but it is not installable
         Depends: libomp5 (>= 0.20140926) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

NOTE: Hugin is compiled from source with manual flags that I needed. I don’t  want to install it from the official repository because it is missing these special flags (use of extra processing power).
However, I tried to remove it, but again, no luck.

By running

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/shutter
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install shutter
```

it results in:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 hugin : Depends: libglew2.0 (>= 1.12.0) but it is not installable
         Depends: libomp5 (>= 0.20140926) but it is not going to be installed
 shutter : Depends: libgtk3-imageview-perl (>= 9) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libgoocanvas2-perl but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libnumber-bytes-human-perl but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libcarp-always-perl but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libgoocanvas2-cairotypes-perl but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

By running:

```
sudo apt-get install shutter
```

it results in:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 hugin : Depends: libglew2.0 (>= 1.12.0) but it is not installable
         Depends: libomp5 (>= 0.20140926) but it is not going to be installed
 shutter : Depends: libgtk3-imageview-perl (>= 9) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libgoocanvas2-perl but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libnumber-bytes-human-perl but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libcarp-always-perl but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libgoocanvas2-cairotypes-perl but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

By running

```
 sudo apt-cache policy hugin shutter libomp5 libglew2.0 shutter libgtk3-imageview-perl libgl1
```

It results in:

```
hugin:
  Installed: 2019.3.0.8297
  Candidate: 2020.0.0-0b1~focal
  Version table:
     2020.0.0-0b1~focal 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntuhandbook1/apps/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
 *** 2019.3.0.8297 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2019.2.0+dfsg-1build3 500
        500 http://ftp.ntua.gr/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
shutter:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.97-1~0linuxuprising1~focal1
  Version table:
     0.97-1~0linuxuprising1~focal1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/shutter/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/shutter/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     0.94-1 -1
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libomp5:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:10.0-50~exp1
  Version table:
     1:10.0-50~exp1 500
        500 http://ftp.ntua.gr/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
libglew2.0:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
shutter:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.97-1~0linuxuprising1~focal1
  Version table:
     0.97-1~0linuxuprising1~focal1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/shutter/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/shutter/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     0.94-1 -1
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libgtk3-imageview-perl:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 9-1~ppa~focal4
  Version table:
     9-1~ppa~focal4 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/shutter/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/shutter/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
libgl1:
  Installed: 1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1
  Candidate: 1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1 500
        500 http://ftp.ntua.gr/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.3.1-1 500
        500 http://ftp.ntua.gr/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
```

By following the instructions of N0bert:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/apps
```

it results in:

```
Updating packages lists
PPA to be removed: ubuntuhandbook1 apps
Package revert list generated:
 audacious/focal audacious-plugins:amd64/focal audacious-plugins-data/focal libaudcore5:amd64/focal libaudgui5:amd64/focal libaudqt2:amd64- libaudtag3:amd64/focal
vokoscreen-ng/focal

Disabling ubuntuhandbook1 PPA from /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntuhandbook1-ubuntu-apps-bionic.list
Disabling ubuntuhandbook1 PPA from /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntuhandbook1-ubuntu-apps-focal.list
Updating packages lists
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Selected version '3.10.1-1build1' (Ubuntu:20.04/focal [amd64]) for 'audacious'
Selected version '3.10.1-1build2' (Ubuntu:20.04/focal [amd64]) for 'audacious-plugins'
Selected version '3.10.1-1build2' (Ubuntu:20.04/focal [all]) for 'audacious-plugins-data'
Selected version '3.10.1-1build1' (Ubuntu:20.04/focal [amd64]) for 'libaudcore5'
Selected version '3.10.1-1build1' (Ubuntu:20.04/focal [amd64]) for 'libaudgui5'
Selected version '3.10.1-1build1' (Ubuntu:20.04/focal [amd64]) for 'libaudtag3'
Selected version '3.0.2-1' (Ubuntu:20.04/focal [amd64]) for 'vokoscreen-ng'
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 hugin : Depends: libglew2.0 (>= 1.12.0) but it is not installable
         Depends: libomp5 (>= 0.20140926) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
  audacious audacious-plugins audacious-plugins-data libaudcore5 libaudgui5 libaudtag3 vokoscreen-ng
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libaudqt2 libtiffxx0c2{u}
The following partially installed packages will be configured:
  hugin{b}
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 7 downgraded, 2 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
Need to get 2,460 kB of archives. After unpacking 1,705 kB will be freed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 hugin : Depends: libglew2.0 (>= 1.12.0) which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package

         Depends: libomp5 (>= 0.20140926) but it is not going to be installed
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Remove the following packages:
1)     hugin [2019.3.0.8297 (now)]


Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
```

After pressing "y", I was able to install Shutter with

```
sudo apt-get install shutter
```

By the instructions of N0bert, how I kept Hugin too...

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/tiff3/libtiff4_3.9.7-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
wget -c https://mirrors.aliyun.com/oldubuntu-releases/ubuntu/pool/main/e/eglibc/multiarch-support_2.15-0ubuntu10.23_amd64.deb

sudo apt-get install -y ./libtiff4_3.9.7-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb ./multiarch-support_2.15-0ubuntu10.23_amd64.deb

wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/glew/libglew2.0_2.0.0-5_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install -y ./libglew2.0_2.0.0-5_amd64.deb


sudo apt --fix-broken install
sudo apt autoremove --purge


cd ~/Downloads
wget -c http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/tiff3/libtiff4_3.9.7-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
wget -c https://mirrors.aliyun.com/oldubuntu-releases/ubuntu/pool/main/e/eglibc/multiarch-support_2.15-0ubuntu10.23_amd64.deb

sudo apt-get install -y ./libtiff4_3.9.7-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb ./multiarch-support_2.15-0ubuntu10.23_amd64.deb

wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/glew/libglew2.0_2.0.0-5_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install -y ./libglew2.0_2.0.0-5_amd64.deb

sudo apt-get install -y ./libtiff4_3.9.7-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb

sudo apt-get install ~/src/hugin/hugin.build/hugin-2019.3.0.8297-Linux.deb
sudo apt-get install libsz2

wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/h/hdf5/libhdf5-100_1.10.0-patch1+docs-4_amd64.deb
dpkg -x libhdf5-100_1.10.0-patch1+docs-4_amd64.deb /tmp/hdf
sudo cp /tmp/hdf/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5_serial.so.100 /usr/local/lib

sudo rm /usr/lib/libhdf5_serial.so.100
sudo apt install libhdf5-103
sudo apt install libhdf5-103 --reinstall
```

Comment: You can install your own Perl (e.g. using [perlbrew](https://perlbrew.pl/)) or use the system Perl with [local::lib](https://perldoc.pl/local::lib). Either way, you'll have to (re)install shutter's dependencies.

Comment: Add the output of `apt-cache policy hugin shutter libomp5 libglew2.0 shutter libgtk3-imageview-perl libgl1` to the question or upload it to pastebin. You probably have broken repositories. Please carefully follow my comments. Without this I can't provide the solution.

Comment: See update question with the relevant output you asked

Comment: Remove newer PPA for Hugin with `sudo apt-get install ppa-purge ; sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/apps` .

Comment: again: `sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/apps
Updating packages lists
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/hugin/hugin-builds/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
Warning:  apt-get update failed for some reason`

Comment: Then run `sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:hugin/hugin-builds` followed by `sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/apps` .

Comment: It seems that you have to agree with proposed solution. And then recompile Hugin again.

Comment: I did it. Note, i can remove Hugin if you would like. Because i have it compiled from source, i can easily regenarate it, its deb package and install it. What you would like to do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127420/discussion-between-n0rbert-and-estatistics).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to cleanup your repositories and fix dependencies first by:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:hugin/hugin-builds
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/apps

sudo apt --fix-broken install
sudo aptitude dist-upgrade
```

And then install Shutter from the [special PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Elinuxuprising/+archive/ubuntu/shutter?field.series_filter=focal):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/shutter
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install shutter
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will be helpful or not, but I had the same issue with Shutter cloned from [git](https://github.com/shutter-project/shutter) and Ubuntu 20.04, this is how I got it to work:

```
sudo apt install libcarp-always-perl libnumber-bytes-human-perl libpango-perl libgtk3-perl libfile-copy-recursive-perl libxml-simple-perl libproc-simple-perl libsort-naturally-perl libimage-exiftool-perl libmoo-perl libgoocanvas2-perl  libproc-processtable-perl
```

Dependencies above are needed to run Shutter 0.99.2 Rev.1593 itself. These
dependencies that are needed to compile the modules doesn't exits in Focal repo:

```
sudo apt install libimage-magick-perl libgoocanvas-2.0-dev
```

Compiling modules with cpan:

```
cpan install Gtk3::ImageView
cpan install GooCanvas2::CairoTypes
```

And these are needed for plugins:

```
sudo apt install libwww-mechanize-perl libjson-maybexs-perl libnet-oauth-perl  libpath-class-perl
```

After I installed all of above the latest Shutter successfully ran on my Ubuntu 20.04 PC.